# reCaptcha Is not loading in Custom Web Browser Desktop Application MFC,C++

Tags: c++, mfc

I have custom web browser which is build using COM and Active X control using C++ or MFC.

In custom web browser  am passing the my URL/Page  which is having code to load the recaptcha " " its not loading buts its working fine in normal browser.
https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js i can see in the fiddler this URL is redirecting to webworker.js, anchor.htm and bframe.htm.
but from custom web browser after this "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js nothing happening i mean its not redirecting to webworker.js, anchor.htm and bframe.htm.

I have use the IDocHostUIHandler if want you can grow through the following links "https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa770041(v=vs.85).aspx#WebBrowser_Customization_Architecture"

I have enable the downloading   in my custom Web Browser i can see the downloaded files such the script, theme, css or html page and also "recaptcha__en[1].js" in machine expect webworker.js, anchor.htm and bframe.htm.

Please Help me out.

Thanks and Regards

Comment: Try to set [`FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330730(v=vs.85).aspx#browser_emulation) in the registry. Embedded IE runs in compatibility mode by default, which can brake pages that need newer browser version.

Comment: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION\TempHtml.exe set the key "REG_QWORD = 11001" even though it does not resolve the issue.